# Posting to an iframe - page rendered within the iframe instead of parent frame

Tags: javascript, php, html, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm implementing 3D secure.  It requires a form to be auto submitted inside of an iframe, so that the response can show a bank username/password box within said iframe.

```
<form id="3D_form" target="3D_iframe" action="<?php echo $acsurl; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="<?php echo $pareq; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="<?php echo $md; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="<?php echo $termurl; ?>" />
</form>

<iframe name="3D_iframe" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" src="<?php echo $acsurl; ?>"></iframe>
```

Once the user enters their username/password a success code is posted to a URL I also supply to the original iframe post (TermUrl).

Problem is, the TermUrl renders a page with my websites theme/template WITHIN the iframe, so I get a page within a page if that makes sense?

I'm using Joomla.  My TermUrl is a function within a controller like:

http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_mycontroller&task=mycontroller.callback

Any idea how I can either render a BLANK webpage within the iframe, or better yet, just re-render the entire page WITHOUT an iframe...?  Currently I have to reload the page using Javascript from my callback function:

```
function callback() {
    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
    echo "<head>";
    echo "<title>Form submitted</title>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.location = 'http://mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_mycontroller&view=myview'</script>";
    echo "</head>";
    echo "<body></body></html>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `die;` at the end of your **function** in controller. 
I guess this will work out and wont open Iframe in and Iframe